# Constructing a std::string_view from a braced std::string, clang and gcc disagree with -Wconversion

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, c++17

GCC 7.2 and clang 5.0 seem to disagree about the following code when compiled with `-std=c++17 -Werror -Wconversion`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string s = "Hello, World";
    std::string_view vs{s};
    std::cout << std::string{vs} << '\n';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled with `clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -Wconversion`, it compiles correctly (see https://godbolt.org/g/JZn8cL)

However, GCC 7.2 issues a somewhat perplexing diagnostic (see https://godbolt.org/g/kmYbJ3):

```
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
7 : <source>:7:26: error: choosing 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::__sv_type() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::__sv_type = std::basic_string_view<char>]' over 'constexpr std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_string_view(const std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' [-Werror=conversion]
     std::string_view vs{s};
                          ^
7 : <source>:7:26: error:   for conversion from 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::basic_string_view<char>' [-Werror=conversion]
7 : <source>:7:26: note:   because conversion sequence for the argument is better
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Compiler exited with result code 1
```

Both compilers compile the code fine after changing `vs{s}` to `vs(s)`.

Which compiler is right here? Is brace initialization of a `std::string_view` from a `std::string` running afoul of conversion rules somehow, and clang is failing to issue a diagnostic when it could/should? Or is GCC in the wrong and the diagnostic is erroneous?

Comment: Is that a warning or error?

Comment: @NicolBolas It is a warning but issued as an error due to -Werror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which compiler is right here?

Both? Compilers are allowed to give warnings, or not, as they choose. It's just that when you write:

```
std::string_view vs{s};
```

You might be under the impression that this is doing something like aggregate initialization or at least invoking a `string_view` constructor, but it's not - and maybe that impression isn't as likely to happen if you wrote:

```
std::string_view vs(s);
```

so gcc gives you a warning (since you asked for one).

The code is fine. Both compilers are fine. Just use `()`s to initialize, there's no reason to use `{}` here (there is no difference in behavior in the two approaches).

Comment: I understand that compilers are free to issue warnings as they see fit, but they aren't allowed to issue false positive diagnostics! So I guess, read my question as "is this a false positive diagnostic from GCC'. However, where you say 'at least invoking ... a constructor, but it's not' makes me doubt that it is. At the same time, it leaves me puzzled. If that expression isn't constructing a std::string_view, what is it doing? I have no problem changing the code to use ()'s but I want to know why first.

Comment: @acm How would the compiler know if it was a false positive or not? They have heuristics, usually they're right, sometimes they're not. And it's constructing a `string_view` by way of `string`'s `operator string_view()`, not via a constructor.

Comment: Of course the compiler can't know, but we can still discuss whether the heuristic is behaving appropriately. Warnings should highlight potential problems with the code that should be addressed. Either this code is correct, in which case the warning heuristic seems to be being overzealous, or there is something wrong with this code, in which case I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: "they aren't allowed to issue false positive diagnostics" That is exactly what you have requested. `-Wall` means "please warn on some things that are valid C++ (but might still be a mistake)" and `-Werror` means "please issue diagnostics for warnings". Together, they mean "please issue diagnostics for some things that are valid C++"

Comment: I would find this answer more useful if it helped explain how the `{s}` and `(s)` versions differ.  The diagnostic is not quite comprehensible to me, and I would have thought that both forms are invoking a std::string_view constructor.

Comment: @acm: "*Warnings should highlight potential problems with the code that should be addressed.*" A "potential problem" does not mean an *actual* problem. `if(x = 5)` is a "potential problem" because despite being perfectly legal, 99.9% of the time you really meant `if(x == 5)`. But sometimes... you really did mean the first one. That's why it's a warning; because the compiler cannot *know* that the valid code is wrong. I don't agree with GCC warning over this, but you did pick `-Wall`, which often warns over things that shouldn't be warned over.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I don't disagree. But I still don't have a clear answer to my original question. Is there anything wrong with the code as written? One tool I trust is silent but accepting, the other says 'maybe'. If the answer is that the code is fine as is, then I'm suggesting that GCC's heuristics could be improved here, as I expect that `string_view sv{s}` is going to be a very common pattern, written by lots of programmers. It is very common to enable `-Wall -Werror` by default in builds, and to treat all warnings as serious.

Comment: @acm: "*But I still don't have a clear answer to my original question. Is there anything wrong with the code as written?*" Barry answered you: "The code is fine. Both compilers are fine." "*It is very common to enable -Wall -Werror by default in builds, and to treat all warnings as serious.*" Very common for who? I tried that once, and got thousands of spurious, pointless warnings. `-Wall` is not the default *for a reason*.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Fair enough as to having answered the question, I missed the last sentence in the above answer while discussing the comments.

Comment: Also, does the `vs(s)` version actually behave differently?

Comment: @M.M No, not here.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question ("is this invalid C++?") has now been answered ("no."), but it's clear from the comments you're now interested in why gcc warns about this valid code. That is a more interesting question.

Removing the template arguments, the warning reduces to this:

```
warning: choosing 'std::string::operator std::string_view()' over 'constexpr std::string_view(const std::string_view&) ' [-Wconversion]
```

So it's warning about a user-defined conversion operator being chosen over a constructor... but that constructor couldn't actually be used for conversion. Here is another example that warns for the same reason:

```
class A {  // Like string_view
public:
    A() {}
};
class B {  // Like string
public:
    operator A() {return A();}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a{b};
}
```

This gives:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
12 : <source>:12:10: warning: choosing 'B::operator A()' over 'constexpr A::A(A&&)' [-Wconversion]
     A a{b};
          ^
12 : <source>:12:10: warning:   for conversion from 'B' to 'A' [-Wconversion]
12 : <source>:12:10: note:   because conversion sequence for the argument is better
12 : <source>:12:10: warning: choosing 'B::operator A()' over 'constexpr A::A(const A&)' [-Wconversion]
12 : <source>:12:10: warning:   for conversion from 'B' to 'A' [-Wconversion]
12 : <source>:12:10: note:   because conversion sequence for the argument is better
```

By the way, adding e.g. `A(int)` constructor does not add anything to the warning, so it is focused on the move constructor and copy constructor of `A`. Deleting the copy and move constructors with `=delete` does not change the warning either.

This clarifies what is causing the warning, but not why it warns. The gcc [documentation for `-Wconversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says:

> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes conversions between real and integer, like `abs (x)` when `x` is double; conversions between signed and unsigned, like `unsigned ui = -1;` and conversions to smaller types, like `sqrtf (M_PI)`. Do not warn for explicit casts like `abs ((int) x)` and `ui = (unsigned) -1`, or if the value is not changed by the conversion like in `abs (2.0)`. Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers can be disabled by using `-Wno-sign-conversion`.
>
> For C++, also warn for confusing overload resolution for user-defined conversions; and conversions that never use a type conversion operator: conversions to `void`, the same type, a base class or a reference to them. Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless `-Wsign-conversion` is explicitly enabled.

So it depends on what you consider to be "confusing overload resolution for user-defined conversions". Perhaps the gcc devs consider `A a{b}` to look like a call to a constructor of `A`, and so they consider it calling `B::operator A()` to be "confusing".

Or perhaps it is indeed a bug... Given that this seems to be a rarely-used warning flag (it's not even in -Wall), and given how strange the "choosing x over y" messages are, that is quite possible.